# How to get docker version in container?

Tags: docker, containers

I want to know the version of docker when I'm inside a container.

I know that `/proc/self/cgroup` can tell me if I'm in a container. But how about the version?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute command on host machine while you are inside a container.

```
ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "docker -v"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the docker api from inside the container to query the docker engine https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/ specifically you can use this endpoint https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/SystemVersion

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer @EduardoBaitello it's as simple as calling GET /version against the docker api

Answer (score 0):

The first and **safe approach** that I will recommend is to pass the docker version to the container as an environment variable.

```
docker run -e DOCKER_VERSION="$(docker -v)" -it --rm alpine sh -c "echo \$DOCKER_VERSION"
```

The second approach can be is to [mount host docker-socket](https://medium.com/better-programming/about-var-run-docker-sock-3bfd276e12fd) but you should know about this [risk of docker-socket](https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/) just for getting the version of docker.

```
docker run --rm -it  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine ash -c "apk add --no-cache curl && curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/version"
```